# Is it idiomatic to say "Something is gotten from somebody"?

Tags: passive-voice

For a sentence

> I got this book from Tom,

if we simply rewrite it with passive voice, it would seem to be like

> This book was gotten from Tom.

But I haven't quite met such expressions as

> Something is gotten from somebody.

Is it idiomatic to say so?

Comment: From "50 tips for better English": "The passive voice is to be avoided" (also: "Always avoid alliteration." and "Be more or less precise.") ;-)

Comment: Google Books shows quite a few examples of "was gotten", mainly from US court reports and similar transcripts of colloquial speech.  It sounds a bit odd to me, but I'm British, and we don't say "gotten". I'd strongly prefer to use the active, or if you must put "this book" first, maybe "This book came from Tom" or "This book is/was from Tom".

Comment: For the sake of clarity, the passive voice is to be avoided *if there's no good reason to use it*.  But there are plenty of occasions where the passive is perfectly grammatical and idiomatic.  Sometimes **is gotten from** is used like "is caught from" in a public health disease-transmission context in American English speech.

Comment: @StuartF I'm American and it sounds unnatural to me, too. It might be general avoidance of passive voice, or just that this verb is rarely used with it. Maybe because it has an irregular past tense.

Comment: Isn't the US dialect's *gotten* used more in the sense of *become*? "I've gotten married" or "I've gotten a dog" (become a dog owner), "I've gotten flu" (become infected).

Comment: Results (experimental, mathematic, etc) are **gotten by** or **gotten from** following certain steps.  So **gotten** can also mean "derived" or "arrived at" or "achieved" or "obtained" in addition to "acquired".

Comment: @WeatherVane:  With BE the thing gotten is the subject. With HAVE the getter is the subject.  Some diseases ***are* gotten** from drinking bad water and others from breathing in virus-laden aerosols.   The travelers ***have* gotten** an intestinal parasite.

Comment: @Tim does that take it back to the *passive voice*?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to by *that*.  BE gotten is the passive.

Comment: BE gotten in AmE is not always colloquial or informal. You'll find plenty of scientific and mathematical texts where results are gotten.

Comment: I did not say 'colloquial or informal'. A 'dialect' doesn't express either. AmE is a dialect, with its own formal and informal usage. Although if you cannot see beyond its shores, you might not realise that. Obviously the language you grew up with, is 'right'.

Comment: @WeatherVane: my comment about "colloquial" was in the context of a comment made earlier by StuartF about the Google Books attestations coming mainly from colloquial AmE sources.  Sorry for that confusion.   But to your point, British English itself has multiple dialects, and so does American English.

Answer (score 1):

A little searching turns up a few results, most dated, some rather formal.

> What an opportunity there might be here if what people fear of
> landlords is true, that by pressure they will get an agreement in
> writing, or, at any rate, that the tenant may well say at a later
> date: "I did not understand; **this agreement was got from me** by
> intimidation, pressure and misrepresentation:" It is much better to
> let matters stand as the Bill prescribes, and leave it to the tenant
> to go to the local authority to obtain the certificate of disrepair
> (British Parliament, House of Lords, 1954)
>
> The hon: Member may not know that **my information was got from Lord
> Aberdeen and from Sir John Ross**, the Commissioner of Police: Of
> course, if the hon: Baronet knows better than either of them, I will
> sit down and listen to him: (British Parliament, House of Lords, 1914)
>
> The men of the elfmound, both kings and nobles, have been wooing me; but nought **was gotten from me**, because ever since I was able to speak, I have loved thee and given thee a child's love for the high tales about thee and thy splendour. (Harvard Classics)
>
> On cross-examination, he said: "He wrote to me (i.e. in way of conversation) that the first will **was gotten from him** by false pretences. (New Brunswick. Supreme Court · 1883)
>
> Well, she was questioned through an interpreter, and an affidavit **was gotten from her** also. (Warren Commission · 1964)
>
> Did not Mr. Perkins claim that his authority to deliver these lectures and receive compensation therefor **was gotten from you**? (United States. Congress. Joint committee to investigate Interior dept. and Forest service. 1911)

In the right context, these sound perfectly natural (idiomatic).

Comment: "This book was gotten from Tom" doesn't sound like it has the right context. // I'd not use 'idiomatic' for 'acceptable in rarefied registers'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The Merriam-Webster dictionary defines _idiomatic_ as '(2) peculiar to a particular group, individual, or style'. This is the very definition of idiomatic. I do agree that without context it is difficult to say whether 'this book was gotten from Tom' would be a good choice.

Comment: Oxford Languages (the 'Google definition'; I'm not sure how best to attribute these nowadays) also lists that as the second sense. The first, default, sense is 'using, containing, or denoting expressions that are natural to a native speaker'. The verier definition of the word. [CACD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/idiomatic) even has 'correct without being too formal'. A more helpful answer would use 'idiomatic in the  "normal within certain registers" sense' to avoid confusion. People still think 'pertaining directly  to idioms' is the default sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to be a comment, but since there haven't been any answers yet, I'll give it a shot.

The passive with got sounds peculiar to me. The reason has to do with the semantics of *got* and the voice of the passive construction. My dialect uses *got* to emphasize and focus on the act of acquiring something, whereas the passive voice is used to tone down and de-emphasize agency in general.

Consider

> I see he got himself a new tattoo/car/girlfriend.

vs

> I see he obtained himself a new tattoo/car/girlfriend.

The second one sounds terrible to me because *obtained* is in conflict with the emphatic personal pronoun. *Obtained* de-emphasizes what *himself* is trying to emphasize. But *got* is felicitous when collocated with *himself.*

Using the passive construction with *gotten* often creates the same sort of conflict.

[image: he got, was got, was gotten]
[image: he acquired, was acquired]
[image: he obtained, was obtained]

*Was obtained* is 4 times as common as *he obtained*.
*Was acquired* is 1.8 times as common as *he acquired*.
*Was gotten* is 0.0018 times as common as *he got*.
*Was got* is 0.11 times as common as *he got*.

Comment: And now I can see an earlier answer.

Comment: note that the graphs accidently use a capital H in the *he*. A small h was used when I derived the ratios in the last paragraph.